How do I go about identifying / using this (exotic?) .db file?
I own a Synology DS220J which I use to host a few different NFS shares / "Shared folders" (as DSM calls them), and I was snooping on some files in order to find out where the thing is storing information about them.
I found an interesting file that contains my "Shared folders" names in /usr/syno/etc/synoshare.db:
% strings synoshare.db 
BACKUP.OLD
HOMES
BACKUP
[REDACTED STRING]
LAVORO
[REDACTED STRING]
WEB_PACKAGES
STORAGE
NETBACKUP
[REDACTED STRING]
TFTP

I copied this file over from the NAS to my local machine, and the first thing I tried to do was to interact with it as if it was an SQLite database:
% sqlite3 synoshare.db 
SQLite version 3.44.0 2023-11-01 11:23:50
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .databases
main: /home/dev/playground/temp/synoshare.db r/w
sqlite> .tables
Error: file is not a database

Then I resorted to file -k:
% file -k synoshare.db
synoshare.db: Berkeley DB 1.85/1.86 (Btree, version 3, native byte-order)\012- Berkeley DB 1.85/1.86 (Btree, version 3, little-endian)\012- data

file seems convinced it's a Berkeley DB file. So I tried using db_dump (db_dump doesn't come with a man page on openSUSE, so I referred to Oracle's db_dump man page, which suggests using -l to list the databases in a file):
% db_dump -l synoshare.db
db_dump: __db_meta_setup: synoshare.db: unexpected file type or format
db_dump: open: synoshare.db: Invalid argument

What should I try next? I understand this database may be structured in some sort of proprietary format, but how likely would that be? And it appears to bear some resemblance with Berkeley DB files anyways, so perhaps I could use some trick to convert it to a proper Berkeley DB file?

Note, there is a pdf that describes a few args you can apply to the cli synoshare to add/edit entries, but not how to dump the info.

@meuh Thanks! That's very useful to know as I'm now resorting to scrape the data using the API used by the web interface, which at least returns JSONs, and I sure could use avoiding having to send HTTP requests to update the values

Kinda anticlimactically, the issue was simply that recent versions of db_dump don't support Berkeley DB 1.85 files.
You'll need db_dump185.
openSUSE doesn't seem to provide a package that contains db_dump185, however Ubuntu does (libdb1-compat), so I scped the file over to a Ubuntu machine and installed libdb1-compat:
sudo apt install libdb1-compat

From man db_dump185:

The  db_dump185  utility reads the version 1.85 database file db_file and writes it to the standard output using a portable flat-text format understood by the db_load(1) utility.

So I first converted the file using:
db_dump185 synoshare.db >synoshare_converted.db

Then, I installed the db-util package (which provides db_load and db_dump) and ran:
<synoshare_converted.db db_load synoshare_converted_db_load.db

Finally I was able to dump the contents of the file (kinda - as what's shown is a lot of strings mixed with bytes represented as hexadecimal - but that's a problem for another day) using:
db_dump -p synoshare_converted_db_load.db

% db_dump -p synoshare_converted_db_load.db
VERSION=3
format=print
type=btree
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
[...]
DATA=END

